# Two select Error “Every derived table must have its own alias” in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to mysql I am trying to combine two select queries but it gives me an error of Every derived table must have its own alias but I gave both the alias already, I will really appreciate any advice

I wanted to check whether the   t1.start1,t1.end1,t1.tool1,t1.mall1 are all in 
                        subquery t2.start2,t2.end2,t2.tool2,t2.mall2 where status is not booked or withdrawn

```
        like my data in t1

                     start1              end1                 tool1            mall1       parentid
                    01/02/2016          01/07/2016           mat1             mallA        id11
                    01/01/2017          01/05/2017            mat4             mallB       id11





                data in t2 status are all  not booked or withdrawn

                start1              end1                 tool1            mall1       parentid
                01/01/2016          01/08/2016           mat1             mallA        id22
                01/01/2017         01/08/2017            mat3             mallB        id29
```

the t1 will passed the condition since  t1.start1,t1.end1,t1.tool1,t1.mall1 are all in subquery or in between the two dates start2 and end2 of ubquery t2.start2,t2.end2,t2.tool2,t2.mall2 where status is not booked or withdrawn

```
     SELECT    t1.start1
FROM      (
                 SELECT p1.start_date   AS start1,
                        p1.end_date     AS end1,
                        p1.tool_type_id AS tool1,
                        p1.parent_id,
                        p1.mall_id AS mall1
                 FROM   tbltools p1
                 JOIN   app_fd_iads_reservation b1
                 ON     p1.parent_id = b1.id
                 WHERE  p1.parent_id = "id11") AS t1
LEFT JOIN
          (
                 SELECT p11.start_date   AS start2,
                        p11.end_date     AS end2,
                        p11.tool_type_id AS tool2,
                        p11.parent_id ,
                        p11.mall_id AS mall2
                 FROM   tbltools p11
                 JOIN   tblbooking b11
                 ON     p11.parent_id = b11.id
                 WHERE  b1.status != 'Booked' && b1.status != 'Withdrawn' ) ) AS t2 ON (
  (
    t1.start1 = t2.start2
    OR
    t1.end1 = t2.end2
  )
  OR
  (
    t1.start1> t2.start2
    AND
    t1.end1 < t2.end2
  )
  OR
  (
    t1.start1> t2.start2
    AND
    t1.start1< t2.start2
  )
  OR
  (
    t1.end1 > t2.end2
    AND
    t1.end1 < t2.end2
  )
  OR
  (
    t1.start1 < t2.start2
    AND
    t1.end1 > t2.end2
  )
)
AND
t1.tool1 = t2.tool2
AND
t1.mall1 = t1.mall2
```

Comment: Don't be so keen to do a subquery. What results do you want out of these tables? Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: I wanted to check whether t1.start1,t1.end1,t1.tool1,t1.mall1 are all in 
      subquery or in between the two dates start2 and end2 of ubquery t2.start2,t2.end2,t2.tool2,t2.mall2 where status is not booked or withdrawn

Comment: Your two tables are `tbltools` and `tblbooking`.  Sample data of those would of helped. A description that was the original requirement rather than a crude reword of the SQL would of been easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Take t1 as the parent, t2 as the child:

Not sure the date criteria matches however this general form is simplifier. `BETWEEN` matches on equal dates as well.

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM tbltools t1
JOIN tbltools t2
  ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
  AND t1.startdate BETWEEN t2.startdate AND t2.enddate
  AND t1.enddate BETWEEN t2.startdate AND t2.enddate
JOIN tblbooking b 
  ON t2.parent_id = b.id
WHERE b.status NOT IN ('Booked','Withdrawn')
```